# Why image is not reflecting on page properties of touch UI dialog in AEM 6.2 after reloading?

Tags: aem, aem-touch-ui

When I reload the page and open page properties, instead of an image which I uploaded, I find the path of that image (i.e of content folder). Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add more information regarding your question with step-by-step instructions to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It was happening because of the image properties that i had provided was not correct.